# How to raise a toast when a seekbar is used in a videoview?

Tags: android, android-videoview

I am using video view to play files I need to raise a toast when the seekbar is clicked or used to seek video showing the current video duration. Any help?

```
MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this.context);
            mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
            videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
            try {
                videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(url));
            }
            catch (Exception e){
                Log.i("Error","In making connection");
            }
            videoView.requestFocus();
            try{
                videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new android.media.MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPrepared(android.media.MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                        textViewPlayback.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        Log.i("Inside","On prepare");
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        videoView.start();
                        videoView.seekTo(getSeekTime()*1000);
                        textViewPlayback.postDelayed(onEverySecond,10);
                    }
                });
            }
            catch (Exception e){
                Toast.makeText(this.context,"can not play this file",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            videoView.setOnErrorListener(new android.media.MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onError(android.media.MediaPlayer mediaPlayer, int i, int i1) {
                   Log.i("Error in playing","error");
                    return false;
                }
            });

            videoView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(),textViewPlayback.getText(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return false;
                }
            });

        }
```

I am using video-view player to play and control media. I need to know is there any way that I can find out when the seekbar is touched in the video view controls.

Comment: please edit your question to include your current code

Comment: Done, have a look.

Comment: this helps everyone a lot more to get on the same page as you, then you'll get better answers :D so you should always try to include as much code and detail as possible :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this -

Add seekbar below your video view.

```
seekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seek_bar);



videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
        seekBar.setProgress(0);
        seekBar.setMax(recVideo.getDuration());

    }
});




seekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar arg0, int arg1, boolean arg2) {


    }

    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        // Show toast here
    }

    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

    }

});
```

Comment: Thanks, but how to add this code for video view player?

Comment: I have updated the code. Please check if you have any issue please tell.

Comment: I am not using any custom seekbar I am using the one that comes with video view media controls, the automatic controls.